# Starting node.js app as a background process

Tags: node.js, daemon, forever

I have a node.js app which runs until user quits the process. I'm trying to run this app as a background process with [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), however, my app originally outputs something to stdout:

```
process.stdout.clearLine();
process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
process.stdout.write('...');
```

and if I run this app with forever

```
forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log app.js
```

it does run in the background but there's nothing in `out.log` file. If I look at `err.log` I see that problem is in printing something to `stdout`:

```
$ cat err.log 

/Users/err/Sites/js/test/app.js:105
    process.stdout.clearLine();
                   ^
TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'clearLine'
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/err/Sites/js/test/app.js:105:20)
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

I also tried to use [forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor) and wrote a small script:

```
var config = require('./config');

if (config.runInBackground) {
  var forever = require('forever-monitor');
  var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
    max: 1,
    silent: true,
    outFile: 'monitor.out.log',
    errFile: 'monitor.err.log'
  });
  child.on('stdout', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('exited.');
  });
  child.start();
} else {
  // do the regular process.stdout.write('...');
}
```

But my script exists without writing any file or starting a background process.

How can I run my node app in the background and write the original `stdout` to some log file? Or even better, is it possible to have an option (let's say in `config.js` file) to run this app as a background process or not, and if so, all `stdout` stuff should be written to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify an absolute path for your files.

That said, there are alternatives to forever that might work depending on your operating system. [node-windows](http://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) and [node-mac](http://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac) both offer what you're looking for. [node-linux](http://github.com/coreybutler/node-linux) isn't ready yet, but the project has some init.d scripts that could be configured to run processes with logging.

*Disclosure:* I am the author of all three of these.